# IntelliJ compiling shows errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I have the following error:

[image: Error]

But the problem is all the things that "don't exist" actually exist. Here:

[image: Proof #1]

[image: Proof #2]

[image: Proof #3]

I've tried the following:

- Restart IntelliJ (multiple times)
- Double check all the imports and package names.
- Removed all imports and reimported them.
- Invalidate caches/restart.

None of this has solved my problem. The weird this was, I ran this code. It only errors now, and all I've done was change my `build.gradle`. Could that be the cause? Let me know if you need my code.

Comment: What did you change in build.gradle? Does the project still build in the command line?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I changed the version of my project, and what do you mean with/how do you build in the command line?

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Compilation errors are shown. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Comment: Command `gradle build`

Comment: @cricket_007
17:05:17: Executing external tasks 'gradle build'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'gradle' not found in root project 'Arraybot'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.911 secs
Task 'gradle' not found in root project 'Arraybot'.
17:05:21: External tasks execution finished 'gradle build'.

Comment: Edit your question to clarify. Do not add comments for clarification. Comments will not always be shown. You make it hard to help you. Post your the relevant parts of your Gradle build script, and what you changed. Always post as text, not screen shots. People want to copy & paste your code to reproduce the problem, they don't want to re-type your code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this, I have no idea what I did or how I did it, it just started working.